# How does spring-ldap bypass OpenLDAP's "unique" overlay? And how do I stop it from doing this?

Tags: java, spring, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I have an OpenLDAP deployment with uniqueness constraints on certain attributes (created with the "unique" overlay), which I have tested using ldapadd and confirmed to be working properly. But when I add a conflicting entry using the "bind" method of org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate, the entry is saved without being validated.

Is this supposed to happen, or is there something buggy about one of my environments? And if it is supposed to happen, how do I get spring-ldap to stop sneaking past the uniqueness constraint?

Comment: Are you doing this by any chance while logged in as the manager?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to be the problem. It happens even when the user I'm binding as is distinct from the rootdn and has only 'write' access. And strangely, when I have Apache Directory Studio bind as the rootdn, it is still restricted by the uniqueness constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be due to a known issue with OpenLDAP, if spring isn't explicitly adding the RDN attribute when it adds the entry:

http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-bugs/201210/msg00065.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring LDAP uses JNDI for communication with the LDAP Server. By default JNDI sends ManageDsaIT control. If set the OpenLDAP Server ignores the unique overlay.

You can disable this behaviour by setting the following environment variable:

```
java.naming.referral=throw
```

When using a spring boot service you can set:

```
spring.ldap.base-environment:
  java.naming.referral: "throw"
```